# Hibernate can't read many to many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many to many mapping: users and rooms, as follow:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users", indexes = {
        @Index(unique=true, columnList="uid"),
        @Index(unique=true, columnList="backendAccessToken"),
        @Index(columnList="backendAccessToken", name="idx_backend")
})
public class User extends BasePersistable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1492535311821424305L;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String nickname;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer uid;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String backendAccessToken;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String location;

    @Column
    private String company;

    @Column
    private String avatar;

    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String accessToken;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date memberSince;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Room.class, cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name="room_users",
                joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="user_id") },
                inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="room_id") })
    private List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Room.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rooms", indexes = {
        @Index(unique=true, columnList="uid"),
        @Index(columnList="uid"),
        @Index(columnList="fullName")
})
public class Room extends BasePersistable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer uid;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Lob
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String homepage;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String owner;

    @ManyToOne
    private Organization organization;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="room")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="rooms", targetEntity=User.class)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name="private")
    private Boolean _private = false;
```

And when I try to create the schema, I'm seeing this error: 
`A Foreign key refering com.models.Room from com.models.User has the wrong number of column. should be 2`

I did some research, tried to use `JoinColumns` annotation on `User` and didn't worked.

**EDIT**
I found the error: the class `BasePersistable` already defined the `id`. So I removed the `id` from `Room` and it worked. Thanks for the tip Mateusz Korwel and kakashihatake

Comment: Could you put full code of `User` and `Room` entities?

Comment: your join colums name need to refer primary key id's to classes so your room.class id colum name must be "room_id" and user.class must be "user_id"

Comment: `Room` entity contains primary key consisting of the two fields?

Comment: @MateuszKorwel no, the pkey is `id`

Comment: @kakashihatake sorry, I don't think so, since I'm actually creating the table via `JoinTable` I can specify the field names

Comment: your user.class not include ıd field if BasePersistable have id filed this time wrong because your rom.class have two id filed

Comment: @LuizE. I supposed the `id` is declared inside `BasePersistable`? Because `User` not contains field annotated by `@Id`. Or I missed something?

Comment: Edited and added comments; Thanks guys!